# How match different column in file 1 and file2 with awk?

Tags: awk

I have the following two files.

The first file is :

```
 3184 2014-07-28 04:15 global.Remote-Access 10.111.8.25 81.245.6.25 tcp
 3268

 3035 2014-07-28 04:16 global.Remote-Access 10.111.8.12 81.245.6.25 tcp
 3268
```

The second file is:

```
 1 Jul 28 04:12 2014-07-28 id967254(group3)[attribute1 attribute2]
 Tunneling: User with IP 10.111.8.12 10 connected

 1 Jul 28 04:15 2014-07-28 id920767(group2)[attribute3 attribute4 ....
 attribute n] Tunneling: User with IP 10.111.8.25 connected

 1 Jul 28 04:16 2014-07-28 ID926072(group3)[attribute1 attribute2]
 Tunneling:User with IP 10.111.8.12 connected
```

If the source IP address in the file 1 is equal to file 2 , and if the time (`hh:mm`) and date (`yyyy-mm-dd`) in the file 1 are equal to file2, the third file will be as follows:

```
 3184 04:15 2014-07-28 global.Remote-Access id920767(group2)[attribute3
 attribute4 .... attribute n] 10.111.8.25 81.245.6.25 tcp 3268

 3035 04:16 2014-07-28 global.Remote-Access ID926072(group3)[attribute1
 attribute2] 10.111.8.12 81.245.6.25 tcp 3268
```

How can I realise this using `awk`?

Comment: file1 in your input does not contain any attribute?

Comment: Right, i've edited and remove the group and attribute... :)

Comment: Is this have space `Tunneling: User`?

Comment: Yes there is a space between TUnneling: and User.

Comment: The last line in your input doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2$3$5];next} ($5$4$(NF-1)) in a' file1 file2 
1 Jul 28 04:15 2014-07-28 id920767(group2)[attribute3 attribute4 .... attribute n] Tunneling: User with IP 10.111.8.25 connected
1 Jul 28 04:16 2014-07-28 ID926072(group3)[attribute1 attribute2] Tunneling:User with IP 10.111.8.12 connected
```

Comment: don't work ... the file 1 does not contain attribute, just the source IP, the date and time . if in both file, source IP, date and time are matching then the output should be:                                                              3184 04:15 2014-07-28 global.Remote-Access id920767(group2)[attribute3
 attribute4 .... attribute n] 10.111.8.25 81.245.6.25 tcp 3268

 3035 04:16 2014-07-28 global.Remote-Access ID926072(group3)[attribute1
 attribute2] 10.111.8.12 81.245.6.25 tcp 3268

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR == FNR {t=($4 $5 $(NF-1));
  $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=X;
  $0=$0; $1=$1;
  sub(/].*$/, "]");
  a[t] = $0; next}
  ($3 $2 $5) in a {$4 = ($4 " " a[$3 $2 $5])}1' file2 file1
```